# Cannot boot into GRUB menu after installing and uninstalling Windows 10

Tags: linux, boot, kali-linux, dual-boot, grub

I was using Kali Linux as a primary operating system with dual boot with windows 10 using GRUB. Unfortunately windows 10 failed and I had to reinstall it again. After re-installation, I was not able to boot into the grub menu and tried everything to find any boot settings in windows and that did no work, so I though that if I uninstalled windows that may force the bios to load from the Linux partition. That did not work and it gives me a message saying that no bootable device is found. Now, I am using a live Linux USB. So, is there any way I can restore my Kali Linux system?
Running the `fdisk -l` command gives the following output:

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ sudo fdisk -l                                               
Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: TOSHIBA MQ01ABD1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5993b524

Device     Boot     Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048    1026047    1024000   500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       217702400 1953521663 1735819264 827.7G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       217704448  238675967   20971520    10G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       238678016  349265919  110587904  52.7G 83 Linux
/dev/sda7       349269228  350233064     963837 470.6M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda8       350233128 1931872807 1581639680 754.2G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Partition 7 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/sdb: 14.91 GiB, 16005464064 bytes, 31260672 sectors
Disk model: Cruzer Blade    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x3c89495a

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *         64 6867839 6867776  3.3G 17 Hidden HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sdb2       6867840 6869311    1472  736K  1 FAT12


Disk /dev/loop0: 2.94 GiB, 3155832832 bytes, 6163736 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: First kali as main OS: why. Kali is not a good distro for a main OS. I would remove all mention of it, except as a foot note. It looks like it may have been working for you, and is not the cause of your problems. 2nd and I can't remember how, hence only a comment. Usually you will have one boot loader (grub), the firmware will only see this one. It should be responsible for booting all OSes. MS-Windows, is anti-social, and will remove all foreign boot loaders (this is probably what broke your system). You need to reinstall grub, and get it to search for OSes to boot.

Comment: Is your system old? Or before 2012? You show BIOS/MBR as Windows only boots in BIOS mode from MBR(msdos) drives. Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives since 2012. Since MBR, you can only have one boot loader in MBR and then need grub. But grub only boots working Windows, and then you have to restore Windows boot loader to MBR or use your Windows repair flash drive. Better to use UEFI installs for all systems on gpt drive, but that will erase everything so have good backups of your data.

Comment: I manged to fix the issue by reinstalling Grub, thanks guys